# Edit and remove text chunk from values in a data frame

Tags: regex, r, dataframe

I have the following simple problem.

I have a data frame with a city variable looking like this:

```
  [1] Flensburg, Stadt                    
  [2] Kiel, Stadt                         
  [3] Lübeck, Stadt                    
  [4] Neumünster, Stadt                
  [5] Hamburg, Stadt
```

Now I want to remove the *", Stadt"* chunk in every line. 
Tried with reshape2 but didn't get it work.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

With a regex expression:

```
gsub("(.*?),.*", "\\1", df$V1)
[1] "Flensburg"  "Kiel"       "Lübeck"     "Neumünster" "Hamburg"
```

Comment: Thanks dude! That works for me. Can you explain the logic behind this?

Comment: We are capturing all characters up to the comma and deleting the rest. Regular expressions deserve their own time to learn as they apply to many programming languages. Start with this tutorial and work through the examples http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html